# How to have code both word-wrapped and flush with an example number?

Tags: listings, examples

Using `\verb| |` in an example fails to give word-wrapping.

Using:

```
%! TEX = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true
}
\newcommand{\inlineCode}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily]}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\sloppy

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{lstlisting}
some code here
\end{lstlisting}
\end{exe}


% or

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{lstlisting}
some code here
\end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}

% fails to produce the text flush with the example number, in exactly the same way beyond the different numbering style (I would prefer to be using the gb4e package for consistency).

% Using:

\begin{exe}
\ex \inlineCode{some code}\\
\inlineCode{some more code}\\
\end{exe}

% works, but makes telling lines apart very difficult, unless I input indentation manually.

% Likewise, using:

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{xlistn}
\ex some code
\ex some code continued
\end{xlistn}
\end{exe}

% spaces them too far apart (or it did in my other document... I'm unsure of why there is a difference, perhaps it is to do with my fonts: Gentium Plus for the body; Noto Sans Mono as for the ttfamily - mono DOES = ttfamily? - though this might change if I can find a tt font to fit Gentium better.)

% Thank you.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippets compilable? Then we do not have to guess your used class, called packages related to the issue ...

Comment: Edited the original so that it should be executable. Thank you.